# Analyze stock value

Tags: stocks, investing, historical-data, yahoo-finance

If I'm going to analyze the stocks of Apple, Amazon, Google etc. I will find them on Yahoo Finance and see the historical changes in each stock.

But sometimes the companies make splits and I see big price drops. This makes my analysis wrong. Can I find some historical data which shows the correct development in stock value?

Comment: Is there an option to show "split-adjusted" values that you may be missing as a feature on Yahoo! Finance?

Answer (score 3):

A Bloomberg terminal connected to Excel provides the value correcting splits, dividends, etc. Problem is it cost around $25,000.

Another one which is free and I think that takes care of corporate action is "quandl.com". See an example [here](https://www.quandl.com/GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL-Apple-Inc-AAPL).

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you want to compare the company's values not necessarily the stock price.  Why not get the total outstanding shares and the stock price, generate the market cap.  Then you could compare changes to market cap rather than just share price.